# Como iterar por cada caractere em um std::istream?

Tags: c++, alocação

Em uma `std::string`, a alocação é feita assim; em **chunks** de 128 caracteres <sup>nota</sup>. Ele pega cada caractere do **input** e coloca-o por `std::string::push_back`. Como  posso fazê-lo?

Nota - http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/132947/

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você deve estar procurando pelo [`istream_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/).

Considere um simples exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  istream_iterator<char> iit(cin);

  do 
  {
      cout << *iit;
      iit++;
  } 
  while (*iit != 'z'); 

  return 0;
}
```

Se você entrar com uma sentença em que o último caractere for a letra `z`, por exemplo `FooBarz`, [`cout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) mostrará apenas `FooBar` desconsiderando `z`.

Outro exemplo, agora usando [vetores](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), corrigido:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector <std::string> v;
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> iit(std::cin);
    v.push_back(*iit);

    for ( std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++ )
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E como eu faria isso sem o 'z', mas sim checando quando o cin acabasse?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Você pode usar std::istream_iterator do mesmo jeito que qualquer outro iterador. Para percorrer todos os caracteres da entrada, você vai precisar do iterador de inicio, do mesmo jeito que mostrado na resposta, e do iterador de final, que é simplesmente um std::istream_iterator construído sem passar, nesse caso, o std::cin. Tendo os dois iteradores basta compara-los a cada iteração e quando eles forem diferentes significa que você já leu tudo.

Comment: @DBX8 Eu já conhecia esta técnica; porém, o std::cin entra em um loop, e não sei como quebrá-lo. Como devo fazer que o input seja feito apenas uma vez?

Comment: Também deve ser de sua consciência que o exemplo 2 não dá output. (MinGW 4.8.1)

Comment: Continua não funcionando.

Comment: Para falar a verdade, só conseguir entrar no computador agora. E está funcionando. Mas pense: se eu dou um exemplo próprio para a criação de uma string, como usaria uma string???

Comment: Não entendi sua última pergunta, @LucasHenrique...

Comment: @Sunstreaker pense: se eu estou implementando uma string, como eu usaria uma string?